# asp-append-version renders broken image when using @

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp-append-version

Using Visual Studio 2015 update 3  and ASP.Net Core 1.1 project.

I have the following simple image code working with asp-append-version.

```
<img src="~/images/Tulips.jpg" asp-append-version="true" />
```

The browser view source renders as expected with ?v=version.  And the picture displays.

```
<img src="/images/Tulips.jpg?v=uTUvJWUmAhnbcvwfyJYROibIWGa2nFDTlwxNn1zOgwo" />
```

I now create a dynamic image name by using C# code @HTML.DisplayFor

```
<img src="~/images/Tulips_@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductNAME)_picture.png" asp-append-version="true" />
```

However, the browser view source renders "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StringHtmlContent" instead of the expected image name "Tulips_NAME_picture.png" and gives the broken image icon.

```
<img src="/images/Tulips_Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StringHtmlContent_picture.png">
```

What could I be missing?  I would appreciate any help that can be offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.DisplayFor` is not supposed to be used inside elements but rather to create them, what you should use is simply `@item.ProductNAME`:

```
<img src="~/images/Tulips_@item.ProductNAME_picture.png" asp-append-version="true" />
```

Alternatively, create a helper method for this:

```
public static string GetProductImage(Product product)
{
    return $"~/images/Tulips_{product.ProductNAME}_picture.png";
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<img src="@SomeClass.GetProductImage(item)" asp-append-version="true" />
```

Comment: @cmill glad it worked. Remember to upvote/mark as answer :)

Comment: I marked it green check for answer but the upvote said my reputation was too low to display.  But it said it was recorded.   (new here) Take care!